# How to search through a directory and find corresponding video and xml files and rename?

Tags: python

A list of files contains files of which some begin with the same name but different extensions:

```
kittens.mpg
kittens.xml
puppies.mpg
puppies.xml
catanddog.mpg
catanddog.xml
```

What methodology needs to be implored to determine a file name with the same name and then rename accordingly

Example of rendered result:

```
video01.mpg
video01.xml
video02.mpg
video02.xml
vide03.mpg
video03.xml
```

The attempted solution is horrendous and renders:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'E:/System Volume Information\\WPSettings.dat' -> 'videoE:/System Volume Information\\WPSettings.dat.dat'
```

```
for file in list_of_files:
    for file2 in self.getListofFiles(current_dir):
        try:
            file00, ext00 = os.path.splitext(file)
            file01, ext01 = os.path.splitext(file2)
            if os.path.basename(file) == os.path.basename(file2):
                name00 = 'video' + file + ext00
                name01 = 'video' + file2 + ext01

                if name00 in dictionary.keys():
                    indexer = dictionary[name00] + 1
                    dictionary[name00] = indexer
                    name00 = 'video' + str(indexer) + ext00

                    if name01 in dictionary.keys():
                        indexer2 = dictionary[name01] + 1
                        dictionary[name01] = indexer2
                        name01 = 'video' + str(indexer2) + ext01

                    else:
                        dictionary[name01] = 0
                    os.rename(file2, name01)

                else:
                    dictionary[name00] = 0
                os.rename(file, name00)


        except KeyError:
            print('Key Error')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping track of previous renames is one way. Something like this should work:

```
import os

previous_renames = {}
i = 1
for filename in os.listdir("."):
    namepart = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    if namepart in previous_renames:
        new_name = previous_renames[namepart]
    else:
        new_name = f"video{i}"
        previous_renames[namepart] = new_name
        i += 1
    os.rename(filename, f"{new_name}{ext}")
```